# com: Invalid number of parameters when pDispatch->invoke()

Tags: c++, c, com, mfc, activex

For some reason I must use a COM control in my code. I want to invoke a method exported by the COM control.

idl file:

```
methods: 
    [id(1)] boolean Open(BSTR filepath, BSTR rootname);
```

cpp file:

```
VARIANT pVarResult;
EXCEPTINFO pExcepInfo;
unsigned int puArgErr;
DISPPARAMS pParams;
memset(&pParams, 0, sizeof(DISPPARAMS));

VARIANTARG param[2];
param[0].vt = VT_BSTR;
param[0].bstrVar = filepath.AllocSysString();
param[1].vt = VT_BSTR;
param[1].bstrVar = rootname.AllocSysString();

pParams.rgvars = param;
pParams.cArgs = 2;
hResult = pDispatch->Invoke(id, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,  
             DISPATCH_METHOD, &pParams, &pVarResult, &pExcepInfo, &puArgErr);
```

I get a error say "**Invalid number of parameters**". Where is wrong of my code?
How to pass two strings params to a interface defined in a com control? It seems impossible.

EDIT 1: add more return info. It seems useless.

```
pVarResult = NULL;
pExcepInfo.wcode = 52424;
puArgErr = 1;
```

Comment: Try providing a variant for the result value (pVarResult).

Comment: @JonathanPotter pVarResult is empty after invoke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for you time.
It's my stupid mistake to cause this problem. Because I use MFC library to implement the COM control. And in MFC framework, if you want to export a interface, you must use a macro to declare it. like this.

```
DISP_FUNCTION(MyCtrl, "Open", Open, VT_BOOL, VTS_BSTR VTS_BSTR)
```

What I write is:

```
DISP_FUNCTION(MyCtrl, "Open", Open, VT_BOOL, VTS_BSTR, VTS_BSTR)
```

The comma should not be added between two VTS_BSTR.

Answer (score 1):

```
  [id(1)] boolean Open(BSTR filepath, BSTR rootname);
```

You cannot call this function with IDispatch, it does not have the correct signature.  It can only work when the return type of the function is HRESULT.  A correct declaration would look like:

```
  [id(1)] HRESULT Open(BSTR filepath, BSTR rootname, [out, retval]VARIANT_BOOL* retval);
```

COM functions in general have a very strong requirement to return HRESULT, it is also required to properly marshal the call across apartment boundaries.  It is the only way that a failure error code can be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
VARIANT pVarResult;
EXCEPINFO pExceptInfo;
UINT pArgErr;
hResult = pDispatch->Invoke(id, IID_NULL,  
      LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,DISPATCH_METHOD, &pParams, &pVarResult, &pExceptInfo, &pArgErr);
```

Try providing the other params